# Problem with the Fourier cosine coefficients of $1/(60 + 2 \cos t +0.3 \cos 2t) $

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, fourier-series

In Mathematical Astronomy Morsels, Meeus defines:
$$
A = 60 + 2 \cos t +0.3 \cos 2t
$$
And gives the following expression for calculating the inverse of $A$

```
1/A =  0.016 676 073 03
     – 0.000 553 255 76 cos t
     – 0.000 074 203 29 cos 2t
     + 0.000 002 617 46 cos 3t
     + 0.000 000 141 96 cos 4t
     – 0.000 000 008 85 cos 5t
     – 0.000 000 000 19 cos 6t
```

I did a Fourier cosine series expansion of $1/A$, the coefficients of which are given by:
$$
C_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dt}{60 + 2 \cos t +0.3 \cos 2t} \\
C_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos nt}{60 + 2 \cos t +0.3 \cos 2t} dt
$$
Evaluating the integrals numerically for $ n=1, 2, 3, \ldots 6$,  I get the following for the coefficients

```
  0.016 676 073 104 944
– 0.000 553 255 784 230
– 0.000 074 203 416 170
+ 0.000 002 617 518 128
+ 0.000 000 142 032 216
– 0.000 000 008 907 612
– 0.000 000 000 207 049
```

Problem is, from like 10th decimal place onwards my coefficients and the ones given by Meeus are different (mine are always a hair larger than Meeus).

So why don't the coefficients match?

Comment: The accuracy depends on round off error and the algorithms that a special Computer Algebraic System (CAS) uses. Also, the hardware can affect I think. :)

Comment: Pretty sure it's not due to round off errors. I used Pari/GP and Maxima and also evaluated them manually using trapezoidal rule. Every time I get the same values.

Answer (score 1):

To check your work you can get exact results by some purely algebraic methods.
Introduce the symbol $X= \cos t$ and note that $A$ is a quadratic in $X$:

$A= 60 + 2 X +.30 ( 2X^2-1)$

The quadratic has roots $r_1,r_2= 1/6 (-10 \pm Sqrt[118])$ (I used Mathematica for that, but you should double-check it).
Next you can expand $1/A$ by partial fractions  then expand each of the two partial fraction terms as a Taylor series in $X$.  Finally you can represent
each resulting power of $X$ in these expansions, such as $X^8= \cos ^8 t$ as an explicit trigonometrical polynomial (finite trig series) that has integer coefficients. I suggest that you read about the Chebyshev polynomials for details of that last step.
This is a tediously direct method, but it  introduces no floating-point arithmetic errors.

Comment: shouldn't $A$ be $60+2X+0.3 (2X^2-1)$?